# symfony2 custom console how do I include the container?

Tags: inheritance, symfony, console, undefined-behavior

How do I fetch the container inside a custom console command script?

im hoping to be able to call

```
$this->container->get('kernel')->getCachedir();
```

or

```
$this->getDoctrine();
```

I can call the above two examples inside the controller but not in the command?..  see simplified example below

```
namespace Portal\WeeklyConversionBundle\Command;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Command\ContainerAwareCommand;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Input\InputArgument;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Input\InputInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Input\InputOption;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Output\OutputInterface;

class ExampleCommand extends ContainerAwareCommand
{

    protected function configure()
    {
        $this->setName('demo:greet')
          ->setDescription('Greet someone')
          ->addArgument('name', InputArgument::OPTIONAL, 'Who do you want to greet?')
          ->addOption('yell', null, InputOption::VALUE_NONE, 'If set, the task will yell in uppercase letters')
        ;
    }

    protected function execute(InputInterface $input, OutputInterface $output)
    {
        $name = $input->getArgument('name');
        if ($name) {
            $text = 'Hello '.$name;
        } else {
            $text = 'Hello';
        }

        // this returns an error?
        // $cacheDir = $this->container->get('kernel')->getCachedir();

        // edit - this works
        $this->getContainer()->get('kernel')->getCacheDir();


        $output->writeln($text);
    }
}
```

returns an undefined error message?.. How do I define it?  I thought that by adding ContainerAwareCommand that I would have access to `this->container?`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about using,

```
$this->getContainer()->get('kernel')->getCacheDir();
```

Take a look at the [Getting Services from the Service Container](http://symfony.com/doc/2.0/cookbook/console/console_command.html#getting-services-from-the-service-container) section on [How to create a Console Command](http://symfony.com/doc/2.0/cookbook/console/console_command.html) part of the documention.

**From the documentation,**

By using [ContainerAwareCommand](http://api.symfony.com/2.0/Symfony/Bundle/FrameworkBundle/Command/ContainerAwareCommand.html) as the base class for the command (instead of the more basic Command), you have access to the service container. In other words, you have access to any configured service.

Comment: thanks for this.  Im not sure I want to create a whole new service seems like its adding extra complextity?  Or I could create a service that returns the container?

Comment: @Robbo_UK It was just an example :) The key here is to use $this->getContainer() instead of $this->container. You could then access the 'kernel' service. 

You don't need to create any service, just edit the way you're calling your container.

(I updated the answer)